# STM8L discovery board, wires for the breadboard

Tags: cables, breadboard, wire, prototyping, pins

I don't know if it is the right place to ask, but still

I have a STM8L discovery dev board - http://www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM116/SC959/SS1673/PF250636

which has very small square **male**-type pins. Of what I can measure, it is around 0.025" (or 0.64 mm), if to assume that the size is from default size range.

Now my question is - where could I get a proper set of M/F (female-to-male) wires of that size, because I need to connect this dev-board to my breadboard, and the breadboard itself has pretty much the same size (0.025" or 0.64mm) **female** pins.

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasheet doesn't show the pin header but assuming it is like this

[image]

You can get a female to male dupont cable

[image]

---

Your board uses the 100mil pin header style so the dupont wire I show can be used.
Just do a search for dupont cable male to female, you can find it almost anywhere.

[image]

Comment: But 100mil is 2.54mm, isn't ? It is 4 times bigger than I need, or I'm missing something ?

Comment: @Dmitri 2.54mm (100 mil) is the distance between two pins of the header, this doesn't relate to the diameter/width  of each pin. Isn't your board like the one in the picture above? What I see are this types of pin unless the image tricks me.

Comment: @Dmitri Does you board have [machined round pins](http://www.mattairtech.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/m/t/mt-db-u4-6.jpg) (left side of the image) which are much thinner instead of square ones? The images of the board I find all show square pins.

Comment: Board has square pins. The distance between the pins is around 2 mm.

Comment: @dmitri The 2.54mm distance is center of one pin to the center of the next one (not end of one to start of the other)  and seems to match what you descride.

Comment: Ah! Then yes, it is 2.54 mm! Thanks.
So, you think, for example, this - http://www.ebay.com/itm/40pcs-1-pin-10cm-2-54mm-Male-to-Female-Breadboard-Jumper-Wire-Cable-for-Arduino-/350882445609 will do for me, or not ? As far as I understood 2.54mm is the spacing, not the pin size ?

Comment: @Dmitri Yes that is what you need, it's the same as the one I showed